# rails get total count in has many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm attempting to do some grouping with a custom select count. Here are my models

```
class RescueGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :delete_all

  has_many :emails, -> { where(type: Contact.types[:email]) }, class_name: 'Contact'
  has_many :phones, -> { where(type: Contact.types[:phone]) }, class_name: 'Contact'
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = nil

  enum type: [:email, :phone, :facebook]

  belongs_to :rescue_group
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rescue_group
end
```

I'm attempting to build a scope that will allow me to get a count of all emails for each rescue group so I can show the count in a view.

But if I do this it works and I can get the `email_count` field.

```
RescueGroup.select('rescue_groups.*, count(contacts.id) FILTER(where type = 0) as email_count')
  .joins(:emails)
  .includes(:addresses)
  .group(:id)
  .first
  .email_count
```

But as soon as I add a filter like this:

```
RescueGroup.select('rescue_groups.*, count(contacts.id) FILTER(where type = 0) as email_count')
  .joins(:emails)
  .includes(:addresses)
  .group('rescue_groups.id, addresses.id')
  .where.not(addresses: { state: 'tas' })
  .first
  .email_count
```

It will fail with the following errror

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email_count'
```

It will also fail if I use the first query and attempt to pluck `email_count`:

```
RescueGroup.select('rescue_groups.*, count(contacts.id) FILTER(where type = 0) as email_count')
.joins(:emails)
.includes(:addresses)
.group(:id)
.pluck(:email_count)
```

So my question is how can I get the `email_count` from both of the failed queries above?

Comment: Why can't you just do: rg = RescueGroup.find(x); rg.emails.count ?

Comment: hey @Msencenb, I need to get the results for hundreds of thousands of records, not an individual one.